# Mouseleave event is fired when interacting with Mega navigation on desktop

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have been having an issue where if I hover over blinds and then click between type, room, colour etc, the nav randomly closes itself.

I know why it is closing itself and thats because the `.site-navigation` element has a mouseleave event bound to it to close the mega nav when the mouse has left the component.

```
elSiteNav.addEventListener('mouseleave', handleSiteNavMouseEvent);
```

It is very tricky to replicate but once its replicated the issue happens frequently.

> url: https://www.hillarys.co.uk/ 
>   browser: chrome

Answer (score 0):

Use stopPropagation in the handleSiteNavMouseEvent function

```
handleSiteNavMouseEvent(event){
event.stopPropagation();
}
```

Comment: What did you mean ?

Comment: Did you replicate the bug I described above?